# Eclipse: how to silence API access warnings for specific projects?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

We have tons of Eclipse projects that specify access rules, i.e. they list those packages whose classes are meant to be the API and discourage/forbid access to all other classes.

This is all nice and makes sense EXCEPT when it comes to unit tests. Our unit tests access MANY internal classes and methods in order to verify their expected behavior which unfortunately yields several tens of thousands (really!) warnings. Consequently no one ever checks warnings any more because finding those pertaining to the classes one is working on and modifying are practically impossible to spot.

I find that highly disappointing and frustrating, because many warnings are most valid and helpful.

Is there a way to disable those access warnings for certain projects (e.g. for all projects whose name ends in *.test). Or can one somehow silence/suppress these warnings when stemming from specific projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Give specific `.test` plug-ins explicit permission to see the internal packages. In the *Plug-In Manifest Editor*, go to the *Runtime* tab, add the internal package to the *Exported Packages* **and** then configure the *Package Visibility* to be *hidden from all plug-in expect* your test plug-ins. Under the hood, this generates an `Export-Package` with an `x-friends` directive: `Export-Package: org.example;x-friends:="org.example.tests"`
2. Open the `.test` projects’ *Properties* and *enable project specific settings* for the *Plug-in Development* > *Plug-in Manifest Compiler*. Under *Usage* and *References* you should find options to tweak the warnings to your liking.

Comment: Thanks for that hint plus description! Sounds like the solution to my problem. I'll test this out and then report on how this works. Thanks again!

Comment: Works brilliantly! Meanwhile I also found out, that one can define a bundle as "Fragment" of an other bundle (and implicitly then also gets access to all its inner packages).

Comment: Yes, turning your `eclipse-test-plugin` projects into fragments is a good practice, as you don’t need to `Export-Package` just for testing purposes (`x-friends` is just a hint, after all). Also, fragments have the added benefit that they have all their host bundle’s imports are available to them, so their manifests can be shortened a lot (often, they include little more than an import of JUnit).